# Combine 2 datepicker conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to combine 2 datepicker conditions for showing dates

1. Only Thursday & Saturday must be shown
2. Only dates from next week - .... must be shown

Seperate, they work. But when I combine them only 1 of the 2 works.
I made a fiddle with my code. Here it is. Thank you.

https://jsfiddle.net/y8ojanna/

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 ">
                            <h3>Afhalen op:</h3>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 ">

                            <div id="date"></div>
                                <label>Geselecteerd:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="datefield" name="date" required data-readonly/>
                            </div>

                        </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var selected;
$(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var dayNo = date.getDay();
    var mindate = (7-dayNo);
    $( "#date" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', firstDay: 1,minDate: mindate
    });
    $('#date').datepicker({beforeShowDay: function(date){
        return [date.getDay() != 1 & date.getDay() != 2 & date.getDay() != 3 & date.getDay() != 5 & date.getDay() != 0, ''];
    }});
    $('#date').on("change",function(){
        selected = $(this).val();
        document.getElementById('datefield').value = selected;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will do 2 things:

1. It will show only Thursday & Friday
2. And it starts with next week.(Only dates from next week)

```js
var dateToday = new Date();

$('#visit').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: checkAvailable,
    minDate: '+1w'
});

function checkAvailable(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day == 4 || day == 5)];
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://davidwalsh.name/demo/jquery-ui-css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type='text' id='visit' />
```

I hope this is what you were looking for :)